# DTC and AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, distributed-transactions

We're heading into a new infrastructure:

HyperV, Violin storage & dualsite setup

We're looking into AlwaysOn for dual site, but we are using DTC on many of our systems.

Do you know if the issues with SQL2014 AlwaysOn/DTC only are releated to syncronous AG's?

Comment: @morten,  welcome to the professional site to enthusiastic one. Kindly elaborate few details about your subject matter.

Comment: The question is: Are there any difference in the support for DTC if you choose to do asyncronous AlwaysOn? I assume that the DTC is only on play during syncronous AlwaysOn!?

Answer (score 4):

> Do you know if the issues with SQL2014 AlwaysOn/DTC only are releated to syncronous AG's?

There is a limited support for DTC with AlwaysON running SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2 (CTP2). See : [Cross-Database Transactions Support For Database Mirroring or AlwaysOn Availability Groups (SQL Server)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279.aspx)

For SQL Server 2014 and earlier, [DTC is not supported for AlwaysON or DB Mirroring.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366279(v=sql.120).aspx)

Also, refer to Brent's answer : [AlwaysOn AG, DTC with failover](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/47142/8783)

Comment: +1 for dtc is not supported for alwayson or db mirroring.

Answer (score 0):

We currently are using it and have DTC in place and have not saw any issues. With that being said we have not had the bulk of our user base start to use the secondary replicas. We are slowly starting to move reporting and read related logic to the secondary replicas.

Comment: Have you tested failovers since you are using DTC with AlwaysON ?

Comment: Are you saying you are actually using it directly, or just that the MSDTC service is running?

Comment: The MSDTC service is running is all servers in the AG, we have not tested fail over so far. We are waiting on a extended maintenance window in the coming weeks to test fail over.